# beforeEnter hook on child component transition cancelled by scrollTop layout calculations Vuejs

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, components

I have ran into something really strange in Vuejs.

When I add some layout recalculations in javascript beforeEnter hooks for vuejs animation, the entering animation will be cancelled.

In the following example, if you remove this part from the beforeSlideEnter hook, the animation will run normally. However if you add it back, the entering animation will be gone and the element will appear immediately.

```
let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
console.log(scrollTop)
```

Pls see follow example or codepen example:https://codepen.io/asiankingofwhales/pen/zpQBQM

```js
var Child = {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  components: {
    'my-component': Child
  },
  data: {
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow () {
      this.show = !this.show
    },
    beforeSlideEnter (el) {
      let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
      console.log(scrollTop)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* Enter and leave animations can use different */
/* durations and timing functions.              */
.post-slide-enter-active, .post-slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.post-slide-enter, .post-slide-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <button @click="toggleShow">
    Toggle slide
  </button>
  <transition name="post-slide"
              v-on:before-enter='beforeSlideEnter'>
    <my-component v-if="show">hello</my-component>
  </transition>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping the child components in another div and moved the v-if up into that div, which solved the problem. However I can't figure out why this is happening..

Answer (score 0):

This is currently still not explained and [opened as a bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mounted%20class%20transition). Will update if status changed in the future.

Temporary hack: wrap the child component in another div.